# how to deselect a taxonomy already subscribed while submitting a form

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms, notifications

I have a taxonomy based subscription form which alerts user when we have new posts published under subscribed taxonomy.

Currently, if a user is subscribed to 2 taxonomy, say A and B, and the user tries to subscribe to additional taxonomy, (say C and D), but when selecting chooses A again, the alert says “You are already subscribed to A” and the user has to select again. Instead it should recognize C and D as new taxonomy and subscribe the user to those.

Link:http://codepad.org/rKyZ7nq0

Comment: Is there a particular module that you are using to help accomplish the subscribed via taxonomy term?

Comment: see this http://codepad.org/rKyZ7nq0

Comment: Is this your code or a contrib module on d.o?

Comment: On line 40 there is an check to set if $taxonomy_name isset. In the example from above it will always be set which is why you get the form_set_error triggered.

Comment: This is my code. I basically want to skip out the already subscribed taxonomy so user does not have to select all the categories again.

Comment: I've added your code to pastebin because it has highlighting abilities. http://pastebin.com/bSPBGjiF

Comment: Since this is your own code it will help to also see your form definition code. Otherwise I'm guessing at what data is contained in $form_state['values'].